# hornetq-2.3.0.Final. errors occurred when creating client connection.HornetQException[errorType=INTERNAL_ERROR message=null]

Tags: hornetq

It happens very often to me .
We found it in development environment , most time we close the client process without close the client connection.
A simple way to replicate it , it just open 30+ client connections from remote host in seconds ,and kill the client Process.
so I think if I have 100 client connections from every application server to the HornetQ server , and one of the appserver crash , then no new client connections could be open any more.

after I started and stoped many client coonections ,  new Clients can't connect to Server .
I must restart the server .... thank you for help ..

on the Server side , the logs :

> 2013-07-06 15:31:01 [WARN ] org.hornetq.core.server
>   (ManagementServiceImpl.java:426) - HQ222111: exception while invoking
>   createTopic on jms.server java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor298.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
>           at org.hornetq.core.server.management.impl.ManagementServiceImpl.invokeOperation(ManagementServiceImpl.java:843)
>           at org.hornetq.core.server.management.impl.ManagementServiceImpl.handleMessage(ManagementServiceImpl.java:418)
>           at org.hornetq.core.server.impl.ServerSessionImpl.handleManagementMessage(ServerSessionImpl.java:1513)
>           at org.hornetq.core.server.impl.ServerSessionImpl.send(ServerSessionImpl.java:1274)
>           at org.hornetq.core.protocol.core.ServerSessionPacketHandler.handlePacket(ServerSessionPacketHandler.java:445)
>           at org.hornetq.core.protocol.core.impl.ChannelImpl.handlePacket(ChannelImpl.java:631)
>           at org.hornetq.core.protocol.core.impl.RemotingConnectionImpl.doBufferReceived(RemotingConnectionImpl.java:547)
>           at org.hornetq.core.protocol.core.impl.RemotingConnectionImpl.bufferReceived(RemotingConnectionImpl.java:523)
>           at org.hornetq.core.remoting.server.impl.RemotingServiceImpl$DelegatingBufferHandler.bufferReceived(RemotingServiceImpl.java:564)
>           at org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.HornetQChannelHandler.messageReceived(HornetQChannelHandler.java:72)
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelHandler.java:88)
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:560)
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:787)
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:281)
>           at org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.HornetQFrameDecoder2.decode(HornetQFrameDecoder2.java:169)
>           at org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.HornetQFrameDecoder2.messageReceived(HornetQFrameDecoder2.java:134)
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:560)
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:555)
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.oio.OioWorker.process(OioWorker.java:71)
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.oio.AbstractOioWorker.run(AbstractOioWorker.java:73)
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.oio.OioWorker.run(OioWorker.java:51)
>           at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
>           at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
>           at org.jboss.netty.util.VirtualExecutorService$ChildExecutorRunnable.run(VirtualExecutorService.java:175)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at org.hornetq.core.postoffice.impl.WildcardAddressManager.addBinding(WildcardAddressManager.java:112)
>           at org.hornetq.core.postoffice.impl.PostOfficeImpl.addBinding(PostOfficeImpl.java:453)
>           at org.hornetq.core.server.impl.HornetQServerImpl.createQueue(HornetQServerImpl.java:1850)
>           at org.hornetq.core.server.impl.HornetQServerImpl.deployQueue(HornetQServerImpl.java:1137)
>           at org.hornetq.jms.server.impl.JMSServerManagerImpl.internalCreateTopic(JMSServerManagerImpl.java:1280)
>           at org.hornetq.jms.server.impl.JMSServerManagerImpl.access$800(JMSServerManagerImpl.java:105)
>           at org.hornetq.jms.server.impl.JMSServerManagerImpl$2.runException(JMSServerManagerImpl.java:650)
>           at org.hornetq.jms.server.impl.JMSServerManagerImpl.runAfterActive(JMSServerManagerImpl.java:1832)
>           at org.hornetq.jms.server.impl.JMSServerManagerImpl.createTopic(JMSServerManagerImpl.java:637)
>           at org.hornetq.jms.management.impl.JMSServerControlImpl.createTopic(JMSServerControlImpl.java:481)
>           at org.hornetq.jms.management.impl.JMSServerControlImpl.createTopic(JMSServerControlImpl.java:470)
>           ... 33 more 2013-07-06 15:31:01 [WARN ] org.hornetq.core.server (ServerSessionPacketHandler.java:541) -
>   Sending unexpected exception to the client
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at org.hornetq.core.postoffice.impl.WildcardAddressManager.addBinding(WildcardAddressManager.java:112)

Client:

> Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException
>             at org.hornetq.core.protocol.core.impl.ChannelImpl.sendBlocking(ChannelImpl.java:378)
>             at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientSessionImpl.internalCreateQueue(ClientSessionImpl.java:1987)
>             at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientSessionImpl.createTemporaryQueue(ClientSessionImpl.java:356)
>             at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.DelegatingSession.createTemporaryQueue(DelegatingSession.java:304)
>             at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQSession.createConsumer(HornetQSession.java:559)
>             at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQSession.createConsumer(HornetQSession.java:378)
>             at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQSession.createConsumer(HornetQSession.java:353)
>             at com.gamebean.toolkit.jms.hornetq.impl.MessageBridgeImpl.init(MessageBridgeImpl.java:89)
>             ... 131 more Caused by: HornetQException[errorType=INTERNAL_ERROR message=null]
>             ... 139 more

Comment: IMO this is really a bug report (valid or invalid, doesn't matter). I'll look at it with attention *when I get the time for it* :-P In general, you'd get a lot more attention and a much more timely answer by posting this at the HornetQ forum (https://community.jboss.org/en/hornetq?view=discussions) or by filling it as a bug at https://issues.jboss.org/browse/HORNETQ

Comment: Thank you for reply . I had post this at HornetQ forum 2 times before this , but no useful answer yet. I will try fill it as a bug again.

Comment: From what I can tell Clebert asked for more information, and all you gave back were comments unrelated to the problem's cause https://community.jboss.org/thread/230166 we need the parameters used to create that Topic and the server's configuration to figure out what is happening.